# Custom viewcontroller won't load in tabbed application (iOS / Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a tabbed application that I created using the tab application template. I added a new viewcontroller and linked it up with a segue in the storyboard. In the simulator the third tab shows up in the tab bar, and when I switch to the third tab the "loadView" method gets called (I put an NSLog in there to check).

However, the view is empty (black screen). I can switch back to the other tabs. When I switch back the log message shows up again, but still no view loaded. I made sure to set the class in the identity inspector to the new viewcontroller class for the third view. But I just can't get it to load.

What gives? I'm pretty sure I've done this before. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

- Did you connected the Root UIView from your XIB to your UIViewController's view?

Sometimes you just forget to do that..

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if this applies since I am using the storyboard...does it?